# Parsing variables that are passed to YML

Tags: yaml, yq

I have a yml file that resembles the one below

```
functionbeat.provider.aws.functions:
    - name: cloudwatch
      enabled: true
      type: cloudwatch_logs
      description: "lambda function for cloudwatch logs"
      triggers:
        - log_group_name: "my-application-1"
```

I want to be able to extend `log_group_name` key here.
The idea is the `log_group_name` key is passed in as a list through a variable, for instance

`logGroups = my-application-1,my-application-2,my-application-3,my-application-4`

I am expecting this to translate to this in the yml

```
functionbeat.provider.aws.functions:
    - name: cloudwatch
      enabled: true
      type: cloudwatch_logs
      description: "lambda function for cloudwatch logs"
      triggers:
        - log_group_name: "my-application-1"
        - log_group_name: "my-application-2"
        - log_group_name: "my-application-3"
        - log_group_name: "my-application-4"
```

Is it possible to do this using shellscript or any parser/tool? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you ok to use a third party tool like `yq` for this?

Comment: yes i am ok using `yq`

Comment: @Inian is there a way to achieve this using yq?

Comment: @Inian that is just a sample. I can remove it and have the `yq` logic populate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash along with awk:

First place the original yaml template in a file called elastic:

```
functionbeat.provider.aws.functions:
   - name: cloudwatch
      enabled: true
      type: cloudwatch_logs
      description: "lambda function for cloudwatch logs"
      triggers:
        - log_group_name: "my-application-1"
```

Then use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v lognam=$1 '/log_group_name:/ { split(lognam,arry,",");for (i in arry) { printf "\t- log_group_name: \"%s\"\n",arry[i] } } !/log_group_name:/ { print $0 }' elastic
```

We pass in a variable e.g. "my-application-1,my-application-2". The script then in turn passes the variable through to awk as the variable lognam. For all strings not pattern matching "log_group_name:", just print the line, otherwise, split the variable lognam into an array called arry delimited by "," and then loop through the array printing the contents of the array prefixed with tabs and "- log_group_name: "

Comment: Where do I see the output of this? Does this modify the existing `elastic` file?

Comment: No. You can redirect to another file with e.g ./scriptname > elastic1

Comment: The solution works. However when I redirect it back to another file the formatting changes.

Comment: `awk -v lognam=$1 '/log_group_name:/ { split(lognam,arry,",");for (i in arry) { printf "\t\t\t\t- log_group_name: \"%s\"\n",arry[i] } } !/log_group_name:/ { print $0 }' elastic
` seems to fix it. adding `\t` 4 times seems to fix this. Is this expected?